# Get room members, room's owner and admin at the same time in one query with grouped by id (unique) on PostgreSQL 12

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgresql-12

I want to get room's `member` list, room's owner `member` in case of he doesn't exists in other table and admin `member` at the same time. Currently i fetch them individually.

```
CREATE TABLE public.room_members (
  id               bigint NOT NULL,
  member_id        bigint,
  room_id       bigint,
  group_id  bigint
);


CREATE TABLE public.rooms (
  id               bigint NOT NULL,
  member_id        bigint,
  group_id  bigint,
   name varchar(128)
);


CREATE TABLE public.members (
  id               bigint NOT NULL,
  group_id  bigint,
  username varchar(128),
    is_admin bool default false
);

CREATE TABLE public.groups (
  id               bigint NOT NULL,
  name varchar(128)
);


-- My Group created
INSERT INTO "groups" (id, name) VALUES (1, 'My Group');

-- Create users for this group. We have 4 users/members
INSERT INTO "members" (id, group_id, username, is_admin) VALUES (1, 1, 'Pratha', true);
INSERT INTO "members" (id, group_id, username) VALUES (2, 1, 'John');
INSERT INTO "members" (id, group_id, username) VALUES (3, 1, 'Mike');
INSERT INTO "members" (id, group_id, username) VALUES (4, 1, 'April');

-- April creates a room and he is owner of this room
INSERT INTO "rooms" (id, group_id, member_id, name) VALUES (1, 1, 4, 'My Room'); -- 4 is April

-- April also adds Mike to the room members. But she does not add herself. As she is owner.
INSERT INTO "room_members" (id, group_id, room_id, member_id) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 3); -- 3 is Mike
```

### What I want is:

1. `room_members` list of 'My Room' **(Which is only Mike at the moment)**
2. My Room's owner in case of he didn't add himself to `room_members` table. Because he is the owner of that room **(Which is April)**
3. Plus, admin member **(Which is Pratha)**

And this should be unique. For example, if user add himself to `room_members` and also `owner` then it should fetch member one time only.

### What I tried so far?

```
select * from members
left outer join room_members cm on cm.member_id = members.id
left outer join rooms c on c.id = cm.room_id
where c.name = 'My Room' or members.id = 1
```

I couldn't use group by here either. Also i don't need the all fields. Just `room_members` table fields only.

**See here**: https://rextester.com/XWDS42043

### Expected output for `room_members`:

```
+-------------+------------+------------+
|  member_id  |  group_id  |  username  |
+-------------+------------+------------+
|      1      |      1     |   Pratha   |
+-------------+------------+------------+
|      3      |      1     |    Mike    |
+-------------+------------+------------+
|      4      |      1     |    April   |
+-------------+------------+------------+
```

- **Pratha**: Because he is `ADMIN`
- **Mike**: Because he is member of My Room. `MEMBER`
- **April**: Because she created that room. `OWNER`

`room_members` can be many. I just added only Mike but it can have multiple members including admins and owners.

Comment: Thanks for the quite detailed question! One missing information though, would you please edit your question to show us the output that you expect for room named `My Room`, as tabular text?

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I've added a descriptive output.

Comment: Update: I've fixed one issue. `id` should be `member_id` Because `room_members` has its.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can address this with `UNION`:

```
-- list the admin(s) of the room group
select m.id, m.group_id, m.username 
from rooms r 
inner join members m on m.group_id = r.group_id and m.is_admin = true
where r.name = 'My Room'
union
-- list the members of the room
select m.id, m.group_id, m.username 
from rooms r 
inner join room_members rm on r.id = rm.room_id
inner join members m on rm.member_id = m.id
where r.name = 'My Room'
union
-- recover the room owner
select m.id, m.group_id, m.username 
from rooms r 
inner join members m on r.member_id = m.id
where r.name = 'My Room'
```

`UNION` eliminates duplicates accross queries, so if a user is both member and/or group admin and/or owner of the room, they will only appear once.

In your fiddle, this query returns:

```
id  group_id    username
1   4   1       April
2   3   1       Mike
3   1   1       Pratha
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome @Pratha!